# Single search box with multiple keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, asp.net-web-api, full-text-search

Can someone please share with me a good approach on how to build a query that uses one text box with multiple keywords that pick columns on several DB tables. Please see attached screen shot.

**Requirement**
I will need to define a format rule so the user "must" enter an input search with the following format: [category], [suburb] [postcode]. The code behind logic (web API) can then parse this input (this is where my search query will be parsed). [image: SEARCH IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

If you expect unified output then you can use `UNION`

```
INSERT INTO @resultTable
SELECT serviceid
FROM   (
       SELECT DISTINCT serviceid
       FROM   addresses s
       WHERE  s.suburb = @criteria
              OR s.postal = @criteria
       UNION
       SELECT DISTINCT serviceid
       FROM   categories c
       WHERE  c.categotyName = @criteria
)

SELECT *
FROM services s INNER JOIN @resultTable ON ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that. Is there reason why you would insert into another table first ?

Comment: I'm trying to populate the right search results from the three search params

Comment: There is no particular reason for that temp table, we can have different implementation, cte for example

Comment: Is it possible to do this with linq ?